# ¿Como guardar formato bootstrap de mi php a pdf con dompdf?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, php7, dompdf

tengo un problema con mi código PHP. El problema es que necesito convertir una página PHP a PDF, y estoy utilizando dompdf. Mi mayor problema es, que cuando ejecuto mi código PHP factura.php, el formato esta perfecto del css(el formato lo e dado por medio de bootstrap), por lo que eso esta perfecto. La cosa es, que al pasar el archivo por el siguiente código PHP, que es hacer.php, crea el documento perfecto PDF, pero lo crea sin el formato. ¿Que puedo hacer? os dejo mi código, además de las fotos de como me esta funcionando actualmente.

**factura.php**

```
    <?php
    $mensajePie = "Gracias por su compra";
    
    $time = time();
    $fecha = date("d-m-Y", $time);
    $hora = date("H:i:s", $time);
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap.min.css">
            
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10 ">
                <h1>Ticket de compra</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <img class="img img-responsive" src="#.jpg" alt="Logotipo">
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <strong>Nº de Mesa</strong>
                <br>
                <h1 class="h6">X</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
                <strong>Fecha</strong>
                <br>
                <?php echo "".$fecha." (".$hora.")" ?>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>Precio unitario</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    
                        <tr>
                            <td>X</td> 
                            <td>X</td>
                            <td>X</td>
                            <td>X</td>
                            <td>XT</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Y</td> 
                            <td>Y</td>
                            <td>Y</td>
                            <td>Y</td>
                            <td>YT</td>
                        </tr>
                    
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" class="text-right">
                            <h4>Total</h4></td>
                        <td>
                            <h4>XYT</h4>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                <p class="h5"><?php echo $mensajePie ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**hacer.php**

```
    include_once "./dompdf/autoload.inc.php";
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->set_base_path("./bootstrap.min.css");
ob_start();
include "./factura.php";
$html = ob_get_clean();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->render();
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=factura.pdf");
echo $dompdf->output();

?>
```

**IMAGENES**

[image: factura.php]

[image: hacer.php]